# Cucumber not finding chromedriver

Tags: chrome, cucumber

I'm trying to get Chromedriver to work with my cucumber BDD/watir-webdriver setup. 
1) Cucumber+ firefox: works fine
2) irb + chromedriver: works fine
3) cucumber + chromedriver : doesn't work

Here's the setup I have:
Mac OSX: 10.9.5

chromedriver location:

```
$ which chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
$ ls -lart /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  44 Dec 11 18:08 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -> ../Cellar/chromedriver/2.12/bin/chromedriver
```

Here's my env.rb entries for chrome and firefox (firefox works):

```
case ENV['BROWSER']
  when 'chrome'
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
  when 'firefox'
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
end
```

command line I use to run tests, from project directory:

```
"cucumber features"
```

Error:

```
Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:20:in `executable_path'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:31:in `default_service'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:14:in `initialize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
/Users/user/Projects/new_nuvotv_automation/features/support/env.rb:57:in `new'
/Users/user/Projects/new_nuvotv_automation/features/support/env.rb:57:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/cucumber:23:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've also done the following:

1. I added the chromedriver binary to a directory in the test suite
   project, then added the path to the binary, to the LOAD PATH; didn't
   fix the issue
2. added the chromedriver path to the env.rb by adding
   the following: `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'`

This also didn't work, with exactly the same error above.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I found the solution, or at least got pointed in the right direction.

I edited my env.rb to include the following:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
```

Cucumber now runs fine.